# Caching Issues Windows 2003 - IIS 6

Tags: html, css, caching, iis-6, windows-server-2003

We're having a problem with caching (I assume) on our web server. We operate two web servers in a load balanced configuration. Just recently we've noticed that if you update an image or a CSS class, the changes are not being reflected when the page is refreshed. Whether you hold down shift + F5 or not.

This occurred most recently when I changed a class to apply to a link rather than a span. Irritatingly nothing changed, this includes after restarting IIS and recycling the app_pool. In the end I copied the CSS file, renamed it and linked to the new file with the new class in the header and that changed the web page.

I had the same problem with some images. I need to change 6 images on a page as the client wanted them to be longer. I changed the images in Photoshop, overwrote the old ones and uploaded them to the server. Nothing changed. In the end I had to rename the images and rename the img tags in the HTML.

I have tried adding:

```
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

To the master page, but this has not made any difference.

If you have any suggestions they would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Darryl

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that the issue is server-side. Did you try deleting your browser cache? How about visiting the site with a different browser?

Comment: Hi Josh, we've tried it in Opera, Safari, Firefox, IE and Chrome. Will try the browser cache and report back, though it is unlikely as some of the browsers I have mentioned haven't been used in months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a problem with < v4.6 of Umbraco, not publishing correctly to load balanced servers.

We have endless problems with the load balancer and are giving serious consideration to breaking it and going with a single server and keeping the secondary server as a fail-over.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of load balancer you are using, if there is any kind of web accelerator on the load balancer it may be that the caching is happening on the load balancer rather than the web servers or the browser.  You may want to try accessing one of your web servers individually to see if the problem persists.

Comment: Difficult to say Rob, I'll contact our IT guys and see if there's some testing we can do. Thanks for your help.